# Rolling back a failed SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to implement a ROLLBACK functionality on my stored procedure that executes 2 UPDATE queries. I want the second update to only run if the first update was successful. Also if the second update fails, there should be a rollback of the first update statement. I did the below but I need to confirm from you guys if what I wrote is okay. Here is my stored procedure

```
BEGIN
    declare exit handler for sqlexception
    BEGIN
        rollback;
    END;

    declare exit handler for sqlwarning
    BEGIN
        rollback;
    END;

    START transaction;
        FIRST UPDATE

        SECOND UPDATE

    COMMIT;

    SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO res;
    END
```

Comment: Test it and find out. When you mean "successful" do you mean "completed without errors" or "actually updated rows"?

Comment: SQL code looks okay you defined EXIT handlers for SQLEXCEPTION and SQLWARNINGS.  if the first UPDATE has anny off the above the matching exit handler will kick in and ROLLBACK the first update and terminates execution.. The second UPDATE query can only run when the first update runs without SQLEXCEPTIONS and SQLWARNINGS.

Comment: Please someone suggested I turn autocommit to zero, how does this help?